# jQuery Toggles Plugin (Toggle Buttons)

Tags: javascript, toggle, slidetoggle, jquery

I'm trying to get this toggles plugin to work but I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toggles'
```

The plugin doesn't give too much implementation information so I figured it would be straight-forward. I know the plugin script is linking correctly and I have jquery above that. Here's my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="toggles-modern.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="toggles.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="toggle"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">$('.toggle').toggles();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get this plugin working exactly? The plugin resources are here:

https://github.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles

http://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/

Comment: stupid questions have you downloaded the toggles.js and uploaded them to your test environment?

Comment: can you provide us a jsfiddle?

Comment: @LiamSorsby Yup, it's linked, 100%. I can't provide a fiddle since GitHub isn't a CDN I can't include the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps at all....

I use "https://rawgithub.com" to do CDN as that is what they suggest.... **HOWEVER** this is **NOT** meant for production type environments so don't do that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles/master/toggles.min.js"></script>
```

```
$(function () {
    $('.toggle').toggles();
});
```

I seem to have it working with including the file directly from github... Do you have errors in your dev console?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/fJ6gF

**Please note: In the js fiddle i included two external resources on the left panel****

Comment: Not to discredit your answer, it did work. Turns out my script link is using `href` instead of `src`

Comment: Ha, sometimes the easiest answer is the best :P I didn't even notice that is what i typed in my script... force of habit i guess

Comment: And thats why its important to keep the developer tool console open when dealing with js.